# implementing a GUI interface in Django for adding File & Dir to Version Control System

Tags: python, django, version-control

I am implementing a GUI interface in Django for adding File & Dir to Version Control System.I mean i will pass File or Directory data to django view and from view i want to commit these data to specific repository.

Till now i was experimenting with Pyvcs but i couldn't find it more suitable as it is OK just for view any specific repo information.Please share If anyone have any idea which  can help me to achieve my aim.

Comment: What type of version control system? SVN, Git, Merc?

Comment: Actually i have to commit file or dir to any kind of repository from django view in which i have both directory path as well file object.

Comment: Then py-vcs is your best bet (other than implementing your own version on top of specific APIs for all the version control systems out there).

Comment: Would you please show me how can we commit using py-vcs? i spent 4 days on experimenting with py-vcs..!! :(

Comment: Commit isn't supported in that codebase, so you'll have to patch and add that feature yourself. But it's a solid place to start from since it already handles abstracting commits for you. You'll have to add a new method to each of the backends to handle the commit though.

Comment: That's the problem i was facing with it..!!

Comment: Sorry. Nothing out there I know of does commits across all VCS's. It might exist, but I haven't seen it.

Answer (score 0):

py-vcs is your best bet (other than implementing your own version on top of specific APIs for all the version control systems out there).